# Passing in bash arguments from a variable that has quotes

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, compiling, nginx

I'm trying to build an Nginx module.  The instructions I had found have this configure line:

```
./configure --add-dynamic-module=my-module-path $(nginx -V)
```

Which runs without error but the module that it creates does not work.  I was able to get it working by extracting the parameters from `nginx -V` and building it manually.

After getting it working, I attempted to automate the process and created the following script:

```
apt-get source nginx
cd nginx-`nginx -v 2>&1 | sed 's/[^0-9.]*//g'`
CONFIG=`nginx -V 2>&1 | tr '\n' ' ' | sed 's/^.* configure arguments: //g'`
echo "./configure --add-dynamic-module=my-module-path $CONFIG"
./configure --add-dynamic-module=my-module-path $CONFIG
make
```

When running the bash script, the configure fails with `./configure: error: invalid option "-O2"`
Now if I take the line that is echoed and run that, it works flawlessly.

```
./configure --add-dynamic-module=my-module-path --prefix=/etc/nginx --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx --modules-path=/usr/lib/nginx/modules --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --lock-path=/var/run/nginx.lock --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/client_temp --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/proxy_temp --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/fastcgi_temp --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/uwsgi_temp --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/scgi_temp --user=nginx --group=nginx --with-compat --with-file-aio --with-threads --with-http_addition_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_flv_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_mp4_module --with-http_random_index_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_secure_link_module --with-http_slice_module --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_v2_module --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module --with-stream --with-stream_realip_module --with-stream_ssl_module --with-stream_ssl_preread_module --with-cc-opt='-g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/data/builder/debuild/nginx-1.17.6/debian/debuild-base/nginx-1.17.6=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC' --with-ld-opt='-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,--as-needed -pie'
```

The error is caused by this parameter, the -02 is supposed to be in quotes and not processed directly by configure but passed to CC

```
--with-cc-opt='-g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=.....'
```

I also tried quoting double quotes around $CONFIG, which ran but gave me different errors:

```
dirname: unrecognized option '--sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx'
Try 'dirname --help' for more information.
```

I even tried putting the whole thing in backticks but I get `line 6: ./configure:: No such file or directory` with an extra colon which is odd.

How do I get the params from $CONFIG to properly be recognized in ./configure

Comment: `nginx -V` gives more than just the configuration arguments line, which is going to throw a wrench into your attempts here.  Have you considered *escaping* the quotes with backslashes before passing it in?  such that `'-g \'-O2 ... \''` is similar more to what you'd end up passing to `--with-cc-opt`.

Comment: Probably the right way to approach this is to use an *array* - with a properly quoted expansion as described here: [problem escaping quotes in script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/556880/problem-escaping-quotes-in-script). I don't know enough about what `nginx -V` does to post an answer, however you may find the bash `mapfile` (aka `readarray`) function useful for assembling the argument array from the command output

Comment: @ThomasWard The contents of nginx -V are parsed out when I create $CONFIG.  I did attempt escaping but has issues generating the output I needed, idk why I didn't go further down that path.

Comment: @steeldriver That looks promising.  I did start working on a solution using that and it got complex, then a simple idea popped in my head.  Send the echo output to file and run the file, worked as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the solution I went with, it's simple and solves the problem, though not very clean.  Create a new shell script with the command and run that.

```
apt-get source nginx
cd nginx-`nginx -v 2>&1 | sed 's/[^0-9.]*//g'`
CONFIG=`nginx -V 2>&1 | tr '\n' ' ' | sed 's/^.* configure arguments: //g'`
echo "./configure --add-dynamic-module=my-module-path $CONFIG" > tempconfigure.sh
chmod 755 tempconfigure.sh
./tempconfigure.sh
rm tempconfigure.sh
make
```